# How do I restore deleted rc.local file?

Tags: scripts, startup, autostart, startup-applications

I have recently inserted some strings into a script to be loaded on startup through `/etc/rc.local`.
One of them was: `xbacklight -set 50`. This led to Ubuntu refusing to go past login screen so I was forced to remove both files- the script and `rc.local`.

The question is how do I restore the `rc.local` file in order to be able to start over with the script?

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 with kernel 3.7.8.

Comment: By default `rc.local` does nothing. To restore it you might simply create rc.local in /etc containing `exit 0` only. This will restore the default rc.local   
  Quote:   

`#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

exit 0`

This actually leads to a notion that perhaps your script does not exit with 0 or any other error?

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to create a new `rc.local` through:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

paste the code:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

exit 0
```

Make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```